# Passing MQTT Client Object Between JMeter Thread Groups

Tags: jmeter, mqtt

I have a requirement to pass MQTT Client Object between multiple thread groups as MQTT object (not string). All the JMeter elements like Property, Inter-Process Communication, vars.getObject are considering the values in String type.
Question: How can I use this client object in another thread group with same object mqtt object type.

Please help!!!

Thanks
Pawan

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

If you want to store an object into a JMeter Variable you should use [vars.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) function to store the value and [vars.getObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject-java.lang.String-) to read the value

If you're intending to pass the object to different thread (no matter in this or other Thread Group) you need to use `props` shorthand like:

```
props.put('some-key', your-object-here)
```

and later on you will be able to read it as:

```
Object myObject = props.get('some-key')
```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)